# Ajax api call success function not firing

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-core-webapi

My ajax function is not firing the success function below is the code

```
           $.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,  
            url: 'https://localhost:44399/api/users/authenticate',
            type: "POST",
            //headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data: ({
                User_nm: $("#txtUserName").val(),
                User_pw: $("#txtPassword").val()
            }),               
            success: function (resp) {                    
                    alert(1);                                                       
            },
            error: function (xhr, error) {
             //
            },

        });
```

WEB API METHOD is as follows:

```
    public IActionResult Authenticate([FromForm]Users model)
    {
        var user = _userService.Authenticate(model.username, model.userpassword);

        if (user == null)
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password is incorrect" });
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret));

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString())
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        // return basic user info and authentication token
        return Ok(new
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            Username = user.User_nm,             
            Token = tokenString
        });
    }
```

Why the ajax success is not hitting , I tried with datatype: 'json' also. Any other suggestion?

Comment: What is your `Users` model?It seems it contains username and userpassword.But you return user.User_nm.Could you provide your model?

Comment: You could debug the code.If `user==null`,it would hit the error function.You could add `alert(error)` to your error function.